# Construct a sequence of $C^1$ functions that converges to a piecewise linear function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, piecewise-continuity

Consider the piecewise linear function defined by
$$y_0(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\in[-1,0]\\x&x\in(0,1]\end{cases}$$
I want to find a sequence of function in the domain
$$D=\{y\in C^1[-1,1]\big|y(-1)=0,y(1)=1\}$$
that uniformlly converges to $y_0$.

Generally, when given a piecewise linear function $y_0$ defined on $[a,b]$, whether there exists a sequence of functions in $D=\{y\in C^1[-1,1]\big|y(a)=y_0(a),y(b)=y_0(b)\}$ converges uniformly to it?

Comment: @SangchulLee Sorry, it should be $y(1)=1$. Updated.

Comment: Indeed, any continuous function $f$ on $[a, b]$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials, thanks to the [Stone–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: @SangchulLee Amazing theorem. Let me check its details. Thank you for your help!